# HelolW rdlo (A threading challenge)

Tags: code-golf

I have a challenge for you:

- Print "Hello World" using any language.
- Each character must be printed from its own, unique thread

That's it. Obviously, as there's no guarantee that the threads will operate in the order you start them, you have to make your program thread safe to ensure the output is printed in the right order.

And, because this is code golf, the shortest program wins.

**Update:**

The winner is [Marinus' APL entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5886/4139), at 34 characters. It also wins the prize for the least readable entry.

Comment: A better name for this would have been `HelolW rdlo`

Comment: Ha, I like that. Changing it right away :D

Comment: Aww... it's too short

Comment: It is funny to see how many people ignore the "obviously, as there's no guarantee that the threads will operate in the order you start them" hint and think they got it right.

Comment: Albeit it's true that "there's no guarantee that the threads will operate in the order you start them" in practice they will almost always do for such a trivial program. 
To avoid this confusion I'd add to the problem that each thread *must*
1) wait a (small) random number of milliseconds
2) output its char
3) wait for another random (maybe long) amount of time

This way people could tell if the code works by just running it a couple of times. And the join() solutions would perform much worse.
Without random waiting one could be mislead by a successful run to think that his program is correct.

Comment: @silviot That's a bit of an issue, but the point of this was to see how people deal with threading screw-ups without even encountering them (and how they compress those solutions into golf-sized programs).

Comment: @Tharwen are [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) threads?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### APL (Dyalog) (<s>44</s>   <s>43</s> <s>39</s> 34)

```
{⍞←⍺⊣⎕DL⍵}&⌿2 11⍴'Hello World',⍳11
```

Explanation:

- `2 11⍴'Hello World',⍳11` creates a matrix: (H,1), (e,2), ...
- `&⌿` means: for each column of the matrix, do on a separate thread:
- In a thread, `⍺` is now the character and `⍵` is now the time
- `⎕DL⊃⍵` waits for `⍵` seconds.
- Then, `⍞←⍺` outputs the character.

Comment: You know what? I'll take your word for it... :)

Comment: OK, this is the shortest. Congratulations!

Answer (score 19):

### C, <strike>61</strike> 62 chars

```
i;main(){write(1,"Hello World\n"+i++,1);i>13||fork()||main();}
```

The pthread library functions all have loooooong names, so instead I fired up an entire separate process for each character. `fork()` is so much shorter.

It was necessary to use `write()` instead of `putchar()` because the stdio buffering functions are not thread-safe.

**Edited**: Back up to 62 chars. In my zeal, dropping down to 61 chars also dropped the thread-safety.

Comment: It should be possible to changed the write statement to `write(1,"Hello World\n",!!++i)` for 2 bytes. Nice solution otherwise.

Comment: You should try that and see what it produces.

Comment: My mistake, I meant `!!++i`

Comment: That appears to be what you wrote the first time, so I don't see what mistake you were trying to correct. And I wasn't being facetious: I honestly meant that you should try it yourself and see what happens. By removing the addition, every thread will just print the first character of the string.

Comment: I had originally written `!!i++`, but edited it a few seconds later, because I realized it would evaluate to `0` on the first iteration. I assumed you had seen the unedited version. I'm not able to test your code, because it only prints out the very first character, *once*. There's a lot of alternatives though; `i++<13`, using `!!i`, or even `write(1,"Hello World\n",i++>13||fork()||main())`

Comment: The point is that you still have to add i to the string. If you don't then it will only print the first character.

Comment: `fork!=thread` but nice cheat anyway.

Comment: Every process contains a thread, so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 9):

#### Ruby, 46 characters

```
"Hello World".chars{|c|Thread.new{$><<c}.join}
```

It is synchronized due to the fact that the program waits for the thread to end before starting the next thread and continuing with the next char.

Answer (score 7):

## Pythonect (35 chars)

http://www.pythonect.org

```
"Hello World"|list|_.split()->print
```

Comment: This is the shortest so far. Since I have no idea what it actually does, I'll assume it's correct and accept it in a day or two if no-one speaks out against it or posts anything shorter.

Comment: Just had a brief look at the examples.  Shouldn't print statement or list statement have brackets [] around it?

Comment: Hi, im forwarding Itzik's(creator of pythonect) answer: 
'->' and '|' are both Pythonect operators. The pipe operator passes one item at a item, while the other operator passes all items at once.
What the program above does is, it takes "Hello World" string, turn's it into a list, split the list to chars, and send each char to print.
It's possible to optimize the program even further, to the following: iter("Hello World") | print
What it does is, it iterates "Hello World" string, and send each char to print (in a sync/blocking manner).

Regards,
Itzik Kotler | http://www.ikotler.org

Comment: how is the threading being done here???

Comment: Like @LeonFedotov mentioned, and from the pythonect source (available at [pythonect](http://www.pythonect.org)) after parsing, for each iteration and the '->' operator, threading is done like this: thread = threading.Thread(target=__run, args=([(operator, item)] + expression[1:], copy.copy(globals_), copy.copy(locals_), return_value_queue, not iterate_literal_arrays))
thread.start()

Answer (score 6):

### Python (<s>101</s> <s>93</s> 98)

This is Peter Taylor's solution. It works by delaying printing the N-th character by N seconds. See comments.

```
import sys.threading as t
for x in range(11):t.Timer(x,sys.stdout.write,"Hello World"[x]).start()
```

This is the original one:

```
import sys,threading as t
for x in "Hello World":t.Thread(None,sys.stdout.write,x,x).start()
```

It worked because the time it takes to print a single character is less than the time it takes Python to initialize a new thread, therefore the N-th thread would finish before the N+1-th thread was created. Apparently it is against the rules to rely on this.

Comment: You can save 3 chars by changing `import sys,threading` to `import sys,threading as t` and you can save 2 more, by passing the arguments to Thread as positional args, rather than keyword arguments.

Comment: Where is the code that deals with thread safety?
You just fire threads hoping they'll run in the same order you start them.
This won't always be true and is in fact the "hard part" of this problem.
Instead of optimizing your program size you should re-consider the problem: you didn't get it in the first place. See https://gist.github.com/2761278 for a proof that this code doesn't work.

Comment: Quick fix. Use `threading.Timer` instead of `threading.Thread`. Pass in `x` as the sleep parameter.

Comment: Actually see my edit. Had to add an extra line. Back to 101

Comment: Joel's suggestion can be improved by 4 to `for x in range(11):t.Timer(x,sys.stdout.write,"Hello World"[x]).start()`

Comment: @silviot: I was exploiting the fact that thread creation involves instantiating an object, and thus takes one- to two-thirds of a millisecond on the systems I've tested. Character output does not have this overhead, taking only a tenth of this time. Therefore, it will "always" work, as long as you don't override anything. Stdout is buffered so that shouldn't ever give problems either.

Answer (score 4):

## C# 73

```
"hello world".ToList().ForEach(c=>Task.Run(()=>Console.Write(c)).Wait());
```

Comment: not sure this satisfies the requirement that each letter be printed via its own thread since the tpl may reuse threads.

Comment: In theory you're right, but on my pc ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads or ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads returns a value around 1000 for both IO and worker threads.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 28 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prints to stderr. Inspired by [marinus' solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5886/43319).

```apl
'Hello World'{⍞←⍺⊣⎕DL⍵}&¨⍳11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@6R2pOTr5CeH5RTop69aPeeY/aJjzq3fWoa/GjvqkuPo96t9aqHVrxqHezoSFIw38FMCjggtBgNQqGRgqPeucqpKTmJFaCOMWpyfl5KcUKaflFCiUZqQqJSfllqQol@QppmXmZxRkA)

`⍳11` first 11 integers

`'Hello World'{`…`}&¨` for each integer as right argument (`⍵`), spawn the following function with the corresponding character as left argument (`⍺`):

`⎕DL⍵` **d**e**l**ay right-argument seconds

`⍺⊣` discard that (the effective delay) in favour of the left-argument character

`⍞←` print that to stdout without trailing line break

Comment: how about [`⍞∘←&¨'dlroW olleH'`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@j3nmPOmY8apugdmiFekpOUX64Qn5OTqqHOkj6vwIYFHBB6Ed9U118FAwVHvXOVUhJzUmsBLKLU5Pz81IU0vKLFEoyUhUSk/LLUhVK8hXSMvMyizMA)? - I don't know if it's guaranteed theoretically but it seems to always print them in the correct order

Comment: @ngn *Obviously, as there's no guarantee that the threads will operate in the order you start them, you have to make your program thread safe to ensure the output is printed in the right order.*

Comment: that's the constraint I was trying to address, it might be guaranteed. I ran this 100 times and it looks like the thread scheduler always picks up the threads in reverse order. Or at least that's the case when there are ≤11 tasks. AFAIK `⍞∘←` is not interruptible (or is it? maybe you can ask a C developer?). Dyalog implements green threads - 1 real thread pretending to be many, so if a (green) thread switch cannot occur, the order _is_ predictable.

Answer (score 3):

### Java (160 chars)

```
class A{static int i;public static void main(String...a){new Thread(){public void run(){System.out.print("Hello World".charAt(i++));if(i<11)main();}}.start();}}
```

Yeah, I know this is the wrong language for code golf, I do it for fun.

Comment: `class A{public static void main(String[]args){new B(0).start();}}class B extends Thread{int i;B(int j){i=j;}public void run(){System.out.print("Hello World".charAt(i));if(i<10)new B(i+1).start();}}`-197 chars

Comment: @Prince Yep, thanks for the correction!

Comment: `class A extends Thread{static int i;public static void main(String[]args){System.out.print("Hello World".charAt(i++));if(i<11)new A().start();}public void run(){main(null);}}` - 174 chars

Comment: @Wouter Very good one! I totally missed it.

Comment: `class A{static int i;public static void main(String[]a){new Thread(){{start();}public void run(){System.out.print("Hello World".charAt(i++));if(i<11)main(null);}};}}` - 165 chars

Comment: @Wouter Using an instance initializer is a cool improvement, thanks!

Comment: `class A{static int i;public static void main(String[]a){new Thread(){public void run(){System.out.print("Hello World".charAt(i++));if(i<11)main(null);}}.start();}}` - 163 chars

Comment: @bkail Yep, even simpler, not initializers at all.

Comment: @Malcolm,@bkil,@Wouter: `class A{static int i;public static void main(String...a){new Thread(){public void run(){System.out.print("Hello World".charAt(i++));if(i<11)main();}}.start();}}` - 160 chars

Comment: @Prince I thought about varargs, but it didn't come to my mind they could save some chars. By the way, you can only notify one user per comment with the @ notation. Also you don't have to notify me specifically because I am automatically notified about all the comments to my answers.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley Nice :-). I was looking for ways to get rid of that null, but I couldn't think of anything.

Answer (score 2):

#### scala(<s>81</s> 79 chars)

```
def?(l:String){if(l.size!=0)new Thread{print(l(0));?(l.tail)}}
?("Hello World")
```

Comment: A little bit shorter: 
def?(l:String){if(l.size>0)new Thread{print(l(0));?(l.tail)}}

Comment: @JoaEbert:yea,nice

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (<s>120</s> 118)

```
import Control.Concurrent
t=threadDelay.(*3^8)
main=(\(x,y)->forkIO$t x>>putChar y)`mapM_`zip[0..]"Hello World">>t 99
```

I'm not all that sure about multiplying by 9999 - I have a 2Ghz Xeon on which it'll work fine even if you don't, but I also have a Pentium 4 that needs it (999 gave garbled output and 99 didn't do anything at all.)

Comment: Save 2 characters by using `(*5^6)` instead of `(*9999)` and not using backquotes for `mapM_`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail If you remove the backticks you need an extra pair of braces, otherwise it parses as `(((mapM_ (\(x,y) ... )) zip) [0..]) ...` which you don't want.

Comment: As for `999`, it might be getting truncated to 0 due to operating system limitations, but I could be wrong.  What OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

### Bash (64)

```
:(){ [ "$1" ]&&(echo -n "${1:0:1}"&: "${1:1}")};: "Hello World"
```

Comment: @marinus Golfed doen by 3 chars: `:()([ "$1" ]&&(printf "${1:0:1}"&: "${1:1}"));: Hello\ World`

Comment: @fossilet Works for me on both Linux and OSX, several bash versions.  The last one or two characters is sometimes printed after the shell prompt.

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 51 characters

```
"Hello World".each{a->Thread.start{print a}.join()}
```

Answer (score 1):

### D (135 chars)

```
import std.concurrency,std.stdio;
void main(){
    p("Hello World");
}
void p(string h){
    write(h[0]);
    if(h.length>1)spawn(&p,h[1..$]);
}
```

I only start the next thread when I have already printed the current char

edit +2 chars for better bound check

Comment: I get `core.exception.RangeError@test.d(6): Range violation` error.

Comment: @fossilet I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 74

```
"Hello World".zipWithIndex.par.map(x=>{Thread.sleep(x._2*99);print(x._1)})
```

- zipWithIndex produces ((H, 0), (e, 1), (l, 2) ...).
- par makes it a parallel collection.

Tests:

```
(1 to 10).foreach {_ => "Hello World".zipWithIndex.par.map(x=>{Thread.sleep(x._2*99);print(x._1)});println()}
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
...
Hello World
```

Comment: `scala> "Hello World".zipWithIndex.par.foreach(x=>{Thread.sleep(x._2*99);print(x._1)})
Hel lWrolod` - I got this

Comment: Also `println(Thread.currentThread.getName)` shows that the threads are not unique.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: I guess you need one core per letter, so that par will distribute the work over all cores.

Comment: I got it. so one core per letter + high resolution of the system clock required.

Comment: use `map` instead of `foreach`. you can save 4 characters.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: I don't think 100ms counts as high resolution system clock today. I just started 3 (1 to 10)-wrappers around the code, and all 30 ended in sync. Where did you run your code? Map: Okay, it's ideomatically wrong, but for 4 characters, maybe I should do it. ;)

Comment: it's nothing wrong saving 4 characters by ignoring return value. Also `*99` is not required. small values will be mapped to low system resolution. i got wrong values only for the first time. Maybe it's because of start up issues.

Comment: Your solution does not guarantee that each character is printed using a different thread since the parallel collections are using a thread pool and work stealing so it is not predictable. Despite the 99 kittens that died for your Thread.sleep approach.

Answer (score 1):

#### scala(45)

Thread#join based solution

```
"Hello World"map{x=>new Thread{print(x)}join}
```

or

```
for(x<-"Hello World")new Thread{print(x)}join
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (72)

```
(function f(){console.log("Hello world"[i++]);i<11&&setTimeout(f)})(i=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my F# attempt. My first serious F# program. Please be kind.

```
let myprint c = async {
        printfn "%c"c
}
"Hello World"|>Seq.map myprint|>Async.Parallel|>Async.RunSynchronously|>ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

#### C# <s>90</s> 84

```
foreach(var c in"Hello World"){var t=new Thread(Console.Write);t.Start(c);t.Join();}
```

Running version: http://ideone.com/0dXNw

Comment: console.write is very fast which is why this may work for you but is definitely not thread safe!

Comment: @statichippo you're right; I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

### [Go](http://golang.org/)

```
package main
import"fmt"
func main(){o:=make(chan int)
for _,c:=range"Hello World"{go func(c rune){fmt.Printf("%c",c)
o<-0}(c)}
for i:=0;i<11;i++{<-o}}
```

Comment: You don't need to count the characters - we will do so for you!

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang (90)

```
-module(h).
r()->r("Hello World").
r([])->'';r([H|T])->spawn(h,r,[T]),io:format("~c",[H]).
```

Compile `erlc +export_all h.erl`

Answer (score 0):

### Nimrod, 121

```
proc p(c:char){.thread.}=write(stdout,c)
for c in "Hello World":
 var t:TThread[char]
 createThread(t,p,c)
 joinThread(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python: too many characters, but it works.

```
# Ok. First we patch Threading.start to test wether our solution actually works

import threading
import random, time
original_run = threading.Thread.run


def myRun(self):
    tosleep = random.randint(0,200)/1000.0
    time.sleep(tosleep)
    original_run(self)

threading.Thread.run = myRun

# And now the real code:
import time, sys, threading
string_to_write = "Hello World\n"
current_char_index = 0 # This integer represents the index of the next char to be written
# It will act as a semaphore: threads will wait until it reaches
# the index of the single char that particular thread is due to output

class Writer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, char_to_write, index_to_write):
        self.char_to_write, self.index_to_write = char_to_write, index_to_write
        super(Writer, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        ch = globals()['current_char_index']
        while not self.index_to_write == ch:
            time.sleep(0.005)
        sys.stdout.write(self.char_to_write)
        # This will be atomic because no other thread will touch it while it has "our" index
        globals()['current_char_index'] += 1

for i, char in enumerate(string_to_write):
    Writer(char, i).start()
```

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose of randomizing sleep time is.

Comment: @Joel to ensure that, when it works, it's not a lucky coincidence of the threads being executed in the same order as they were fired.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C (183 characters)**

```
-(void) thread {[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(printC) withObject:nil];}
-(void) printC {char *c = "Hello World"; for(int i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++) {printf("%c", c[i]);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell 99 Characters

```
import Control.Concurrent
f[]=return()
f(x:xs)=(putChar x)>>(forkIO$f xs)>>f[]
main=f"Hello World"
```

How it works is each thread starts the next after having displayed its character, so they actually useful stuff can not happen out of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 43 bytes

```bash
xargs -n1 printf<<<'H e l l o \  W o r l d'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyKxKL1YQTfPUKGgKDOvJM3GxkbdQyFVIQcI8xViFBTCgVQRkJOi/v8/AA)

`xargs` forks a separate `printf` process for each character (and waits for it to exit).

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 45 bytes, no external utilities

```bash
eval \(printf\ {H,e,l,l,o,\\\ ,W,o,r,l,d}\)\;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUchRqOgKDOvJC1GodpDJ1UnBwjzdWJiYhR0woGMIiA3pTZGM8b6/38A)

Expands to `(printf H); (printf e); (printf l); (printf l); (printf o); (printf \ ); (printf W); (printf o); (printf r); (printf l); (printf d);` before evaluation. The parentheses make Bash fork a subshell for each letter (and wait for it to exit), but this time `printf` is the Bash builtin.